# Passing nested dict to Django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is it possible to pass a nested dict to Django model?  I have passed single entry dicts before, such as:

```
# create instance of model
m = MyModel(**data_dict)
m.save()
```

But can I nest these entires within a dict to have them all processed vs. iterating through the dict and doing this one-by-one?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: This is looks like deserializing. There's a chapter in the docs about it. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/serialization/

Comment: @DanielRoseman when I pass the nested dict of, which contains multiple model entires, Django will process, and save them all.

Comment: @HåkenLid this should not be required, no?  I can pass a dict today to be processed by a Django model, but this presume the dict has everything for a single entry.  What I am trying to figure out is, can I pass a nested dict, with some allowed structure, to have Django process each nested entry?  The alternative is I walk through the nested dict, and feed each entry to the model, one-by-one to save.

Comment: Why can't you just iterate? What's wrong with that approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) to create multiple model instances in one transaction.

```
data_dict = {
    'jane': {'name': 'jane', 'email': 'jane@example.com'}, 
    'jim': {'name': 'jim', 'email': 'jim@example.com'}
}

MyModel.objects.bulk_create(MyModel(**d) for d in data_dict.values())
```